# Round close to 0 values

Tags: r, built-in

In Mathematica there exists a command called [`Chop`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html) that replaces approximate real numbers that are close to zero by the exact integer 0.

I guess that I can build my own function, something like

```
chop <- function(x, tol = 1e-16) {
    ifelse(abs(x) >= tol, x, 0)
}
```

But is there any built-in function in R already?

**EDIT:** I just want to round values close to 0. For instance:

```
x <- 1e-4
chop(x, tol = 1e-3)
#0
chop(1+x, tol = 1e-3)
#1.0001
```

Comment: Are you looking for `round()`

Comment: @AaghazHussain No, I'm not. `round` function rounds all realls to the closest integer. But I just want to round those that are close to 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zapsmall()` does get you close, but this requires a vector with a rather large number in it to compare.

```
zapsmall(3.5e-5, digits = 4)
#3.5e05

zapsmall(c(3.5e-5, 3.6e10), digits = 4)
#0.0e+00 3.6e+10
```

To display it properly you can wrap it around with format()

```
format(zapsmall(as.numeric(c(3.5e-5, 3.6e10)), digits = 3), scientific = FALSE, trim = TRUE)
# "0" "36000000000"
```

Comment: `round` function rounds all reals to the closest integer. But I just want to round those that are close to 0.

Comment: Below a given tolerance `tol`: `x` is close to 0 if `abs(x)<tol` is true.

Comment: it seems you are looking for `zapsmall()`. I can't seem to get it to work but `?zapsmall` should give you enough insight. I edited my answer with my attempt.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for, but I think it will work for me.

Answer (score 1):

A homegrown solution that gets around the issue of `zapsmall` requiring a large number:

```
small_as_zero <- function(x, ...){
  # ... takes arguments to all.equal
  as_zero <- 
    vapply(X = x,
           FUN = function(x, ...) isTRUE(all.equal(x, 0L, ...)),
           FUN.VALUE = logical(1),
           ...)

  x[as_zero] <- 0
  x
}

small_as_zero(c(0.00001, 0.00000001, 0.0000000001))

small_as_zero(c(0.00001, 0.00000001, 0.0000000001), tolerance = 0.001)
```

Comment: Which is the advantage of using your function instead of the one I gave in my question?

Comment: There isn't any, now that I look at it.  This seems to be a "I tried answering questions before being awake issue."  However, you could make your `chop` function more efficient by using `x[abs(x) <= tol] <- 0` instead of the `ifelse` function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Adjust 0.01 to the tolerance level you like to apply:

```
> x <- c(-0.01,0.0001,2.005,0.3, 0.01, 0.1, -0.1, -0.003)
> ifelse(abs(x) <= 0.01, 0, x)
[1]  0.000  0.000  2.005  0.300  0.000  0.100 -0.100  0.000
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's the same function I wrote in my question. I'm asking whether it already exists in R (what name?) o I need to define it myself.